# How to check if tab is already open when using target="_black"

Tags: html

I have the following snippet of my HTML code:

```html
<div>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Search Google</a>
</div>
```

But I want him to check first if the tab with the URL https://www.google.com is already open and if it is I want to access it. How will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some unique *framename* as value of target attribute, which will open the link in same window if its already opened before:

```
<div>
 <a href="https://www.google.com" target="SomeUniqueName">Search Google</a>
</div>
```

'SomeUniqueName' is name of your tab/frame in this case.

Comment: I guess what OP wants to do is to launch a new tab in the first click on link, and subsequently reuse it when the link is clicked,